# Recorded sound by core audio is distorted and noisy

Tags: c, cocoa, core-audio

I have been trying to record sound using Audio Queue on Mac OS X. Right now, my code works and I can store my recorded sound on file, but when I play the sound, it is distorted, noisy and almost useless. I have adapted my code from official codes(SpeakHere) published by Apple, but it doesn't seem to work. I don't know where the problem lies, but I guess maybe it's the setting of the format, it's like:

```
  AudioStreamBasicDescription recordFormat;
memset(&recordFormat, 0, sizeof(recordFormat));

recordFormat.mFormatFlags =         kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked | kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger;
recordFormat.mFormatID         = kAudioFormatALaw; // 2
recordFormat.mSampleRate       = 16000.0;               // 3
recordFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;                     // 4
recordFormat.mBitsPerChannel   = 16;                    // 5
recordFormat.mBytesPerPacket   = recordFormat.mChannelsPerFrame * sizeof (SInt16);                       // 6
recordFormat.mBytesPerFrame =
recordFormat.mChannelsPerFrame * sizeof (SInt16);
recordFormat.mFramesPerPacket  = 1;                     // 7
recordFormat.mReserved = 0;
```

Any clue on the subject(reasons of recording incomprehensible, distorted and noisy) sound is appreciated.

**EDIT**

I opened the file using CoolEdit Pro. It looked like this:

[WAVE file form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qge5L.png)

Comment: Too much gain resulting in clipped peaks?

Comment: @LinusLecter Try using software like Audacity to analyze the audio wave form.

Comment: What kind of distortion?  What kind of noise?  How are you playing the file?  Why are you using a sample rate of 16kHz?  Can other recorders record the same sound thru the same microphone?

Comment: @hotpaw2 well I have to send the buffers over to a speech recognition server and they demand that freq. I have successfully used AVAudioRecorder to record sound, it works perfect, but I need a stream. If you know of any [third party?] library which gives buffers, I really appreciate it. Since the server wasn't able to recognize the stream of data I used to send, I had it saved on file and I found out that it's completely distorted. Well I don't know what to call that kind of distortion but the thing is, I can't even recognize my own voice.

Comment: What audio file format?

Comment: @hotpaw2 I write LinearPCM on WAV. is that wrong?

Comment: Do you know what using the wrong sample rate (for either play or record) sounds like?

Comment: @hotpaw2 well no. you know, I totally have no idea what's wrong with the code, it was just a guess from a part, which in my opinion, was more prone to error than other parts.

Comment: 16khz sample rate... That means any sound above (about 8khz) will result in distortions being represented in the lower frequencies.   I.E. the 'recording studio' must be absolutely quiet except for the item being recorded and the item being recorded must be completely free of any high frequency elements.  Suggest a software low pass filter with a cutoff frequency around 6khz (around .707 of the nyquist frequency)

Comment: @user3629249 well I recorded perfect segments with AVAudioRecorder on 16k using the same settings as in here. Anyway their server is sensitive to any kind of noise.

Answer (score 0):

The CoolEdit snapshot looks like its reading a file with a 44.1 kHz sample rate linear PCM format.  You appear to be storing 16 kHz ALaw format data into that file, which may be the wrong format for either the data or the file.

Comment: well I don't record Alaw format, in the code it's set to LinearPCM. For the freq you are right, this time I had used 44.1k, but it's the same in 16k anyway.

Comment: The 5th line of code you posted says: kAudioFormatALaw , so ALaw is the format in which you are asking the Audio Queue to record.